# Executing Functions with Different Periods

Tags: algorithm, time

I have to execute some functions in the code and these functions have their own periods values, e.g., `func1` is 5 seconds and `funcN` has 19 seconds of periods.

For this purpose, I have a single variable called `taskTime` that is increased every second. I store the function periods in an array called `periodOfFuncX` where entry `i` represents the period of function `i` (I use 1-indexing). I take the modulo of `funcTime` and the period values to decide if it is OK to execute the functions. Pseudocode is given below:

```
N <- 10 // lets say there are 10 functions
func1() {/* ... */}
func2() {/* ... */}
/* ... */
func10() {/* ... */}

periodOfFuncX[N]
fillPeriods { /* assign period of each function to periodOfFuncX */}

periodLoop()
{
  funcTime <- 0
  fillPeriods()
  while true do:
    if(funcTime % periodOfFuncX[1] == 0) {func1()}
    if(funcTime % periodOfFuncX[2] == 0) {func2()}
    if(funcTime % periodOfFuncX[3] == 0) {func3()}
    /* ... */
    if(funcTime % periodOfFuncX[10] == 0) {func10()}
    delay(1) /* assume 1 second delay */
    funcTime <- funcTime + 1 /* increment the timer. Note that timer is going to overflow and reset when exceeds INT_MAX */
}
```

This method has disadvantages. It is ok that it executes all functions in the first entry but when `funcTimer` overflows and assigned `0`, it violates the periods of functions by causing something like asynchronous execution of all abruptly. Also, sequential execution introduces aggregating delay within and between loops. On the other hand I have only one timer variable which is good. If I add `&& funcTime != 0` to if-checks, functions won't be called in the aforementioned overflow-and-get-0 case.

Do you have another recommendation or comment on the problem I described?

P.S. I am not really sure which tags to assign. Would be happy if you help with tagging.

Comment: Why don't you use something like threads with timers?

Comment: There could be up to 40 of them...  Wouldnt it create a high task burden?

Comment: Once you call ```func1()```, the time to execute it doesn't update the global timer, since the function branches off. Using threading should be the easiest option imo

Answer (score 0):

for smaller N and the periods, try modulo funcTime by the least common multiplier of the periods. Otherwise, I strongly suggest using a list of timers which modulo by their respective periods. It probably will end up with more elegant coding.